# Android esclipe

Tags: android

I have installed sdk, esclipe and avd . Every thing working . But when i select window link and then preference for giving sdk location . Nothing happen there . I give full path where sdk unzipped . I also give sdk tool path but also nothing happen there .I am failed to enable sdk path button ok . I also set path in environment variable but nothing is the result .I am using window xp service pack 3 . Can any one help me . Thanks

Comment: By nothing is result, what are you expecting? You are supposed to create a new android project.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the path you supply ends to early. For example, `c:\Program Files\Android` is not enough. You need tp supply `c:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk`.

Comment: c:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk yes I am supplying this path exactly , but not working .I am also c:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools same result happen .